# With conda/anaconda should I work in (base) all the time?

Tags: python, anaconda

This is a total newbie question, but I installed conda along with a bunch of other stuff like Tensorflow with a virtual environment, and now I'm a little confused.  If I open a terminal my python is pointing to /usr/bin/python.  If I go to the base environment ("conda activate base"), my path points to where I installed anaconda, /usr/local/anaconda2.  Does conda expect that I always go into the base environment to use all the anaconda packages, or did I do something weird on my install that my non-environment still points to the original system python?  Should I just change my path to point to anaconda? I'm on Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: At install, anaconda prompts for whether you want it to add a line to your `.bashrc` (or maybe `.bash_profile`? I forget) which will put your conda python first in your path. Did you decline this? You can always edit one of these files manually to ensure that your conda-installed python shows up first in your path

Comment: I don't remember declining.  There is some added stuff from conda in my .bashrc, but I can't seem to paste it in here properly.  I think it probably has to do with running conda itself though.
    ...

Comment: @user2364295 Edit your question to add it.

Comment: Editing your path is discouraged (see [v4.4 Release Notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)). @Nathan is correct that you should have **base** auto-activate in a default install.

Comment: Thanks for linking those release notes - I've been using `conda` for years, but I just learned that I'm doing a couple things in an outdated way.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of being explicit -- instead of running `python` at the command line, I use the full path to the python interpreter when running scripts (e.g. `/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python`) -- this way I don't rely on the shell behavior or having to worry about which environment is currently active. Running the interpreter using its full path is no different than just running `python` while the environment is active.

But that's not everbody's cup of tea... So...

Even if anaconda did not prompt you to update your `PATH` variable, you can do it explicitly by updating your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (or .zshrc or whatever else) by adding this line: `PATH=/usr/local/anaconda2/bin${PATH}`. Dont forget to re-source the .bashrc or close/reopen your shell for it to take effect.

Conda is capable of creating many virtual environments beyond the base, so if you have more than one and you want to set one as the default, then just update the line above for the appropriate path.

Comment: Editing your path is discouraged (see [v4.4 Release Notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).